# Cannot subscript a value error when trying to parse JSON

Tags: json, swift, dictionary

I'm new to SWIFT, going from Android development, and try to parse json as Dictionary but get 'Cannot subscript a value of type '[AnyObject]' with an index of type 'String' at

```
        if let dict = Utils.convertStringToDictionary(response)! as? [String: AnyObject]{

            if let response = dict["response"] as? [AnyObject]{

                if let first_name = response["first_name"] as? String {//error
                NSLog("first_name = \(first_name)")
                }
            }

        }
```

Just in case, here's the Utils.convertStringToDictionary method :

```
public static func convertStringToDictionary(text: String) -> [String:AnyObject]? {
    if let data = text.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableContainers) as? [String:AnyObject]
            return json
        } catch {
            NSLog("Something went wrong")
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: `as? [AnyObject]` means "as an array of AnyObject" but then you try to access this like a dictionary with `response["first_name"]`...

Comment: thanks ! a lot of new syntax always confuse me. You may make an answer, i'll accept it

Comment: You're welcome. Done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With this line:

```
if let response = dict["response"] as? [AnyObject]
```

you are casting `dict["response"]` as an array containing items of type `AnyObject`.

But then with this line:

```
if let first_name = response["first_name"] as? String
```

you are trying to access this *array* as if it were a *dictionary*.

That's why the compiler tells you

> Cannot subscript a value of type [AnyObject] with an index of type String

because `[AnyObject]` is an array and you cannot subscript an array with a String like with a dictionary, it only accepts subscripting with an index.